# Problem interpreting a "while loop" notation in Python

Tags: python

I am reading and solving through the exercises in the book Introduction to Computation and Programming Using Python by John Guttag (used in the MIT courses) and have a problem understanding why a while loop sets x = 1 at the beginning.

The exercise is asking to find a positive integer that is divisible by both 11 and 12. And the sample solution is:

```
x = 1 
while True:     
    if x%11 == 0 and x%12 == 0:         
        break     
    x = x + 1 
print(x, 'is divisible by 11 and 12')

#prints 132, which is divisible by both 11 and 12
```

I´m sorry that this is such a basic question, but I would appreciate if someone could explain to me the logic of setting x = 1 at the beginning, if x is the value that we are solving for in the first place. Also, I don´t understand the x = x+1 part.

Also, what is the notation I should use to tell a program to do something based on the condition "of all existing integers/values"... (followed by a for or while loop)? Is that what x = 1 possibly refers to?

Comment: Remove it and see yourself!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This program tries to find the first strictly positive integer that is divisible by `11` and `12`.

To do so, you need to start somewhere, and that's a positive number `x = 1`. If we set it to 0, then it will be our result, but we want a strictly positive number.

So we try to see if the new `x` is divisible, if not, we bump it by one.

A better program would be:

```
x = 1 
while x%11 != 0 or x%12 != 0:   
    x = x + 1 
print(x, 'is divisible by 11 and 12')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you not set `x=1` at the beginning you couldn't use `x` as variable because it does not exists in current execution scope.

Part with `x = x+1` is for growing up `x` for next loop iteration.

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm works by verifying all positive integers one by one. It has to start somewhere, and a good place to start is the first positive integer: 1. Hence `x = 1` - means "let's start from 1".

`x = x + 1` sets the value of `x` to the next integer. Imagine for example that `x` is equal to 42. Then the statement conceptually translates to `x = 42 + 1` and in turn: `x = 43`. That's how the algorithm jumps to the next integer to verify.

Answer (score 1):

As per the sample code, it starts to check a number which is divisible by both 11 and 12. So it starts with `x=1` in a range of `[1,ideally infinite)`. The `x=x+1` keeps incrementing `x` by 1 until it encounters a number which is divisible by both the numbers *viz* 132, once it does, it breaks the infinite `while` loop.